# How to change a specific field in multiple files using awk

Tags: awk, scripting

I am very new to script language. I have multiple output files with the names in a similar pattern as: output1 output2 etc.

In each output file, the records follow the pattern as:

```
"295534
4750
4 -0.28 -0.01 -0.03 0 0 0 0 1 425.1 -1 4 0
0 0.28 -0.01 -0.025 0 0 0 0 1 425.1 -1 4 0
0 0.28 -0.01 -0.02 0 0 0 0 1 425.1 -1 4 0
....."
```

What I would like to do is to divide the field in the second line by 100 in each file (i.e. 4750/100). How should I do it?

I appreciate any advice.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us what output you are expecting. Should the original file be modified and the `4750` be replaced by `47.5`? Should the script simply print `47.5`? Should the script print the modified file instead of changing the original? Also, please add your operating system to your question since that will tell us what `awk` implementation you are likely to have.

Comment: In case you only need the result of the division, there is no need for `awk`: `for f in output*; do echo $(($(tail -n+2 $f | head -n1)/100)); done`. I am not sure if all types of shells support that; the Bourne shell probably doesn't.

Comment: @berndbausch that will just be slightly slower than using awk, with more complex and longer syntax, and will break if the number isn't an integer. Also, please don't post solutions in comments because that circumvents the normal QC process of the site since we cannot vote on comments.

Comment: @terdon Strictly speaking, it's not an answer, since OP wants AWK.

Comment: Oh, that's fine @berndbausch. Providing an answer in a different tool is welcome here. The OP might not accept the answer, but it will still be useful to others who might have the same issue but not share the requirement for a specific tool.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'NR==2{ $0/=100 }1' output1 >output1.fixed
```

applying on multiple input files :

```
for file in ./output*; do
    awk 'NR==2{ $0/=100 }1' "$file" >fixed_"$file"
done
```

apply changes on specifc field (if more than a field) and on second line number:

```
for file in ./output*; do
    awk 'NR==2{ $1/=100 }1' "$file" >fixed_"$file"
done
```

`$1` represents first field value, change this to any other field you want to change.